# Looking for an xpath query to select elements in an XML file that have a certain attribute, regardless of the value

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML file loaded into the PHP DOM manipulation system something like this:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('something.xml');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
```

In the XML files are various elements with XMLNS tags similar to the following:

```
<email xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple">example&commat;email.com</email>

<graphic xlink:href="example-image.tif" alt-version="no" mimetype="image" position="float" xlink:type="simple"></graphic>
```

I'd like to strip out attributes such as "xmlns:xlink" and "xlink:type" without removing the elements.

Is there an xpath query that will return every element with an attribute name = "xmlns:xlink" or "xlink:type" or... whatever?

I've tried things like this:

```
$xpath->query('//*[@xmlns:xlink]')
```

or

```
$xpath->query('//*[@xmlns:xlink=*]')
```

But those don't work; I'm just stabbing in the dark.  I haven't really been able to find a good reference for xpath, so some decent reading as well as an answer to the question would be very welcome.  I'm able to generate xqueries for every other relevant scenario but this one.

Answer (score 0):

`@xmlns` is not actually an attribute that you can query (though it looks like one), but a namespace declaration. It *should* be removed as soon as its obligatory, so all subelements and their respective attributes using that namespace are removed (out of that namespaces).

You can query all elements and attributes in a namespace by using this XPath expression:

```
(
  //*[namespace-uri(.) = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink']
    |
  //@*[namespace-uri(.) = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink']
)
```

*(newlines can be ommitted)*

---

For accessing the attributes in `xlink` namespace, you've got to register that namespace using the `xlink` prefix and the URL given in the declaration in the `<email/>` element. Refer to the manual of the XPath API you're using.

This will return all elements with an `@href` attribute in `xlink` namespace:

```
//*[@xlink:href]
```

To find all attributes in `xlink` namespace in XPath 1.0 (both PHP's internal APIs only support that), you need to filter in a predicate:

```
//*[@*[namespace-uri(.) = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink']]
```

Comment: You can also do `//*[@xlink:*]`, even in XPath 1.0, to find all elements having an attribute in the XLink namespace; or `//@xlink:*` to find the attributes directly.